# I have this error `Every row given must be either null or an array.`

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to call the array in php file `data.php` from javascript `script.js` but I got error : 
`Every row given must be either null or an array.`

and the array looks correct like this:

```
['2019-05-13 00:25:13',27.20,41.00],['2019-05-13 00:26:00',27.20,41.00],['2019-05-13 01:26:03',28.10,39.00],['2019-05-13 02:56:11',28.40,37.00],['2019-05-13 03:26:15',28.40,37.00],
```

```
  function drawLineColors() {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'time');
data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
data.addColumn('number', 'Humidity');
$.get("data.php", function(sensors) {
            data.addRows([
                console.log(sensors)

            ]);

            let rowIndex = data.getNumberOfRows() - 1; //gets the row index of 
            last row
            let lastTime = data.getValue(rowIndex, 0); //gets the first column
            let lastTemp = data.getValue(rowIndex, 1); //gets second column
            let lastHum = data.getValue(rowIndex, 2); //gets third column

            console.log(`${lastTime}, ${lastTemp}, ${lastHum}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) your data inside of `data.addrows()`. `console.log()` is used to log data to your console, not for populating arrays.

Please do:

```
data.addRows([sensors]);
```

Hope this helps